# oracle connection encryption and connection poling

Tags: connection-pooling, c3p0

I have been using c3p0 pool but I could not find any information on how to add connection properties such as shown below to a c3p0 connection pool configuration XML, any help would be greatly appreciated. Not sure if this not supported, any alternatives would be great too. Thanks

```
oracle.net.encryption_client=REQUIRED;
oracle.net.encryption_types_client=RC4_256;
oracle.net.crypto_checksum_client=REQUIRED;
oracle.net.crypto_checksum_types_client=MD5
```

Answer (score 1):

Finally got it working, this is what works for me.

```
<bean id="myDS" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource"
    destroy-method="close" 
    p:driverClass="${db.driver}"
    p:jdbcUrl="${db.url}"        
    p:acquireIncrement="1" 
    p:idleConnectionTestPeriod="60" 
    p:maxPoolSize="${jdbc.pool.size}"       
    p:acquireRetryAttempts="2"
    p:minPoolSize="${pool.initialsize}" 
    p:testConnectionOnCheckout="true"
    p:preferredTestQuery="select 1 from dual">
    <property name="properties">
    <props>
            <prop key="user">${db.username}</prop>
            <prop key="password">${db.password}</prop>           
            <prop key="oracle.net.encryption_client">REQUIRED</prop>
    <prop key="oracle.net.encryption_types_client">RC4_256</prop> 
    <prop key="oracle.net.crypto_checksum_client">REQUIRED</prop>               
    <prop key="oracle.net.crypto_checksum_types_client">MD5</prop>           
    </props>
    </property>
```